# Validation with data - Laravel Excel Maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I am performing a simple validation with Laravel Excel for the import of records through a CSV. I would like to know if there is a way to use Laravel Form Requests in an excel validation with the Rules() method.
I have a field called "store_id," which is contained in each row/record of the CSV file. In another field called "name," I want to make a manual query through a Form Request, but I need to go through the constructor of the store_id of the current row. In a Form Request, to get the value of a field in the current record that I am validating, I use the method "$this->get('field_name')". Similarly, in a normal validation of a request, I can directly use the value of some field in the current record.

**Form Request Example**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:60', new ExampleRule($this->get('store_id'))],
        'area' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:50'],
        'classification' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:2'],
        'logical_path' => ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        'height' => ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        'width' => ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        'long' => ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        'store_id'=> ['required','numeric','gt:0','exists:stores,id'],
        'zone_id'=> ['required','numeric','gt:0','exists:zones,id'],
        /*'occupation'=> ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        'available'=> ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        */
    ];
}
```

**Laravel Excel File Import**

In this, I want to get the value of some field of the current record that is being validated.

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:60', new ExampleRule($this->get('store_id')) /*In this line, there is not "get()" method of the context $this*/],
        'area' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:50'],
        'classification' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:2'],
        'logical_path' => ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        'height' => ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        'width' => ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        'long' => ['required','numeric','gt:0'],
        'store_id'=> ['required','numeric','gt:0','exists:stores,id'],
        'zone_id'=> ['required','numeric','gt:0','exists:zones,id'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just typing `$this->store_id` ? If that doesn't work, how is your route set? Is it containg `{storeId}` or `{store_id}` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. that "$this" is reference to laravel excel class, not form request class. thats why that "$this" doesnt work on laravel excel.
2. You can try change the `$this->get('store_id')` to `request()->get('store_id')`. this is laravel helper to perform request call.
3. If that doesnt work, you need to pass the data from your controller with `request()->get('store_id')` to your laravel excel class constructor, then you can use the variable inside the rules method.